# Exchange 2007 ActiveSync - Recreate IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: iis-6, exchange-server, virtual-directory, activesync

I deleted the Exchange ActiveSync virtual directory from IIS because I do dumb things sometimes.

I'm running Exchange 2007, IIS 6.0, and Windows Server 2008.

Now that my confession is out of the way, I've been trying to recreate it.  I've searched the internet and there seem to be two ways to do this:

Microsoft's way, which revolves around deleting metabase data and letting Exchange automatically recreate the virtual directory.

I tried using Metabase Explorer myself, as well as using Adsutil, but I can't find the metabase the article describes (DS2MB).  When using the command 'adsutil delete ds2mb' I get 'Path requested could not be found'

The other way people use to recreate these directories is with Exchange Management Shell: http://my.opera.com/RavenOverride/blog/2009/06/17/how-to-recreate-all-virtual-directories-for-exchange-2007.

I successfully used the Remove-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory command.  When I run 'Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory', nothing is listed.

But when I try to create a new one using an elevated Exchange shell:

`New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory -WebsiteName "Default Web Site" -InternalUrl https://server.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync -ExternalAuthenticationMethods Basic -InternalAuthenticationMethods Basic`

New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory : An error occurred while creating the IIS 
virtual directory 'IIS://server/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Mic
rosoft-Server-ActiveSync' on 'server'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory -WebsiteName "Default Web Site"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (server\Microsoft-...fault Web S 
   ite):ADObjectId) [New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory], InvalidOperationExcepti
  on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 9321FFDB,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemCon 
   figurationTasks.NewMobileSyncVirtualDirectory

I get this same error if I try adding the virtual directory to other websites as well.

What can I do to fix ActiveSync?

Is my lack of DS2MB in Metabase Explorer a problem?
Am I missing something in my use of New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head on the wall, I ended up removing the Client Access Server role from my Exchange 2007 install, restarting, and then adding the role back.  ActiveSync is now working fine.  I didn't need to reinstall IIS as some guides online suggest.